# Fastest way to check if a String can be parsed to Double in Java

Tags: java, string, double

I know there's a million ways of doing this but what is the fastest? This should include scientific notation.

NOTE: I'm not interested in converting the value to Double, i'm only interested in knowing if it's possible. i.e. `private boolean isDouble(String value)`.

Comment: AFAIK, do a Double.parseDouble(String) on it and it throws an exception if it doesn't start with numbers. (Generalizing here). If you want to do regExs and strip out leading non-number chars that's a different story.

Comment: Well, AFAIK, try-catch tends to be rather slow.

Comment: I'm going to second Rcunn87 on the regex idea, but make sure you compile it and store it statically so that you can re-use it again and again.

Comment: @JHollanti certainly is, I wonder if some here are thinking "developer time" rather than CPU time.

Comment: @JHollanti Rather slow could still be fast enough.

Comment: Yea, I don't know if parseDouble() handles scientific notation though. So in that case a RegEx is the only thing that will work for you. Or some other library.

Comment: @OliverWeiler that's a definite nope, has to be the fastest ;)

Comment: @JHollanti, unless you have a specific idea of how fast it really needs to be I suspect that Double.parseDouble is fast enough. If it really has to be the fastest, you need to write your own custom parser to parser exactly what you want.  iT can be 10x faster than a regex but a lot more code esp if you don't really need this.  Can you say exact how fast it needs it be? e.g. how many nano-seconds?

Comment: @PeterLawrey it has to be as fast as a DeLorean traveling back through time.

Comment: 88 MPH, cool. Its getting the two flaming lines that will be tricky. ;)  BTW: I have written double parsers and formatters which work with direct ByteBuffers and sun.misc.Unsafe memory access to minimise latency and IMHO its OTT for 99% of projects, even those which need to be fast.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah, i'm not aiming for ridiculous. It's enough that it's close to the previous implementation which, before anyone pries, i can't share with you guys. Basically it's enough that i avoid the most obvious pitfalls but i just thought that this'd be a fun couple of lines to drop in here. You know, just 'cause i haven't been that active as of late.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check it using the same regular expression the Double class uses. It's well documented here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29

Here is the code part:

> To avoid calling this method on an invalid string and having a NumberFormatException  be thrown, the regular expression below can be used to screen the input string:

```
  final String Digits     = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
  final String HexDigits  = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";

        // an exponent is 'e' or 'E' followed by an optionally 
        // signed decimal integer.
        final String Exp        = "[eE][+-]?"+Digits;
        final String fpRegex    =
            ("[\\x00-\\x20]*"+  // Optional leading "whitespace"
             "[+-]?(" + // Optional sign character
             "NaN|" +           // "NaN" string
             "Infinity|" +      // "Infinity" string

             // A decimal floating-point string representing a finite positive
             // number without a leading sign has at most five basic pieces:
             // Digits . Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix
             // 
             // Since this method allows integer-only strings as input
             // in addition to strings of floating-point literals, the
             // two sub-patterns below are simplifications of the grammar
             // productions from the Java Language Specification, 2nd 
             // edition, section 3.10.2.

             // Digits ._opt Digits_opt ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
             "((("+Digits+"(\\.)?("+Digits+"?)("+Exp+")?)|"+

             // . Digits ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
             "(\\.("+Digits+")("+Exp+")?)|"+

       // Hexadecimal strings
       "((" +
        // 0[xX] HexDigits ._opt BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
        "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "(\\.)?)|" +

        // 0[xX] HexDigits_opt . HexDigits BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
        "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "?(\\.)" + HexDigits + ")" +

        ")[pP][+-]?" + Digits + "))" +
             "[fFdD]?))" +
             "[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"

  if (Pattern.matches(fpRegex, myString))
            Double.valueOf(myString); // Will not throw NumberFormatException
        else {
            // Perform suitable alternative action
        }
```

Comment: Actually in my case the fastest solution was to just if-else through the whole String using flags and whatnots. But that's because in my case the String is most often really, small (like 3 or 4 characters). As a general solution though, i think this is the best.

Answer (score 6):

There is a handy [`NumberUtils#isNumber`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber(java.lang.String)) in [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). It is a bit far fetched:

> Valid numbers include hexadecimal marked with the 0x qualifier, scientific notation and numbers marked with a type qualifier (e.g. 123L).

but I guess it might be faster than regular expressions or throwing and catching an exception.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for that method?  I don't see why it would be any faster than a regular expression - it's a jumble of loops, comparisons, flags...probably what goes on under the hood with a regex but it's sure ugly to look at.

Comment: @Paul: I had a quick look there (I regret now ;-)) but as long as it works, I don't care. I also don't know whether it will be faster than a regular expression. Remember that regex is a dynamically generated state-machine (although probably *very* optimized).

Answer (score 2):

The Apache Commons NumberUtil is actually quite fast. I'm guessing it's way faster than any
regexp implementation.

Comment: Can you provide a benchmark that replaces this guess with hard facts?

Comment: Also I see `isDigits` and `isNumber` in `org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils`, but nothing to check for `isDouble`. So what method were you suggesting to use?

Comment: isNumber checks for all numbers (look at the docu...)
`Valid numbers include hexadecimal marked with the 0x qualifier, scientific notation and numbers marked with a type qualifier (e.g. 123L)`

Comment: If you only need doubles, you would not want your validator to return true for all other kinds of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to check if a string can be parsed to double:

```
public static boolean isDouble(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int length = str.length();
    if (length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int i = 0;
    if (str.charAt(0) == '-') {
        if (length == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    int integerPartSize = 0;
    int exponentPartSize = -1;
    while (i < length) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
            if (c == '.' && integerPartSize > 0 && exponentPartSize == -1) {
                exponentPartSize = 0;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (exponentPartSize > -1) {
            ++exponentPartSize;
        } else {
            ++integerPartSize;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    if ((str.charAt(0) == '0' && i > 1 && exponentPartSize < 1)
            || exponentPartSize == 0 || (str.charAt(length - 1) == '.')) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am aware that the output is not exactly the same as for the regular expression in the Double class but this method is much faster and the result is good enough for my needs. These are my unit tests for the method.

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnTrueIfStringIsDouble() {
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("0.0")).isTrue();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("0.1")).isTrue();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("-0.0")).isTrue();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("-0.1")).isTrue();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("1.0067890")).isTrue();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("0")).isTrue();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("1")).isTrue();
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnFalseIfStringIsNotDouble() {
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble(".01")).isFalse();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("0.1f")).isFalse();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("a")).isFalse();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("-")).isFalse();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("-1.")).isFalse();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("-.1")).isFalse();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("123.")).isFalse();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("1.2.3")).isFalse();
    assertThat(Utils.isDouble("1,3")).isFalse();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've implement this method instead of the reg exp version and had a massive performance improvement.  using a java profiler I can see that I've gone from 27,000ms just on calls to the reg exp isDouble function to 97ms using yours - with same number of calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to convert it to a double and catching the exception would be the fastest way to check...another way I can think of, is splitting the string up by the period ('.') and then checking that each part of the split array contains only integers...but i think the first way would be faster

Comment: How is throwing and catching fast? Not to mention bad practice? And using a period is not locale safe.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code block and seems like throwing exception more faster

```
String a = "123f15512551";
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        a.matches("^\\d+\\.\\d+$");
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

        try{
            Double.valueOf(a);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
```

Output:

```
1324316024735
1324316024737
1324316024737
```

Comment: You can't rely on doing it once to determine a benchmark. There's just too much variation that could happen, and you don't know the resolution of the milli's clock.

Comment: @glowcoder You are right too many possible variation, also maybe hardware. About milli`s: isnt it a long value including all millis since 1.1.1970?

Comment: What @glowcoder said - do it a million times with a pre-compiled pattern and get back to us.

Comment: Try using `System.nanoTime()` instead of `currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: Yes in Java it's milli's from epoch. But that's not what I mean by resolution. Consider the following: http://ideone.com/KOOP3 Notice how the time milli's go up by 1? Now copy that code and run it on your machine. On mine they go up by between 15-16 per tick.

Comment: @glowcoder @ Paul yep clear now:) sorry for misunderstanding, it would be another topic. also thank you for the new information!

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control, though Java's authors made it difficult to not use `NumberFormatException` that way.

The class `java.util.Scanner` has a method `hasNextDouble` to check whether a `String` can be read as a double.

Under the hood `Scanner` uses regular expressions (via pre-compiled patterns) to determine if a `String` can be converted to a integer or floating point number.  The patterns are compiled in the method `buildFloatAndDecimalPattern` which you can view at [GrepCode here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.buildFloatAndDecimalPattern%28%29).

A pre-compiled pattern has the added benefit of being faster than using a try/catch block.

Here's the method referenced above, in case GrepCode disappears one day:

```
private void buildFloatAndDecimalPattern() {
    // \\p{javaDigit} may not be perfect, see above
    String digit = "([0-9]|(\\p{javaDigit}))";
    String exponent = "([eE][+-]?"+digit+"+)?";
    String groupedNumeral = "("+non0Digit+digit+"?"+digit+"?("+
                            groupSeparator+digit+digit+digit+")+)";
    // Once again digit++ is used for performance, as above
    String numeral = "(("+digit+"++)|"+groupedNumeral+")";
    String decimalNumeral = "("+numeral+"|"+numeral +
        decimalSeparator + digit + "*+|"+ decimalSeparator +
        digit + "++)";
    String nonNumber = "(NaN|"+nanString+"|Infinity|"+
                           infinityString+")";
    String positiveFloat = "(" + positivePrefix + decimalNumeral +
                        positiveSuffix + exponent + ")";
    String negativeFloat = "(" + negativePrefix + decimalNumeral +
                        negativeSuffix + exponent + ")";
    String decimal = "(([-+]?" + decimalNumeral + exponent + ")|"+
        positiveFloat + "|" + negativeFloat + ")";
    String hexFloat =
        "[-+]?0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]*\\.[0-9a-fA-F]+([pP][-+]?[0-9]+)?";
    String positiveNonNumber = "(" + positivePrefix + nonNumber +
                        positiveSuffix + ")";
    String negativeNonNumber = "(" + negativePrefix + nonNumber +
                        negativeSuffix + ")";
    String signedNonNumber = "(([-+]?"+nonNumber+")|" +
                             positiveNonNumber + "|" +
                             negativeNonNumber + ")";
    floatPattern = Pattern.compile(decimal + "|" + hexFloat + "|" +
                                   signedNonNumber);
    decimalPattern = Pattern.compile(decimal);
}
```