# Android parseDouble returns Infinity when it should throw NumberFormatException

Tags: android, parsing, double

I'm trying to determine if a `String` represents a `Double`. I expect the following code to throw a `NumberFormatException`:

```
String s = "type1234";

try {
    Double val = Double.parseDouble(s);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Instead, `val` ends up with `Infinity`. I ran the code in a standard JVM and it does, indeed, throw `NumberFormatException`

It looks like Android is ignoring the leading characters 'typ' and then parsing it as e^1234, which is out of `Double`'s range.

Is this the expected behavior? If so, what is a more reliable way to determine if a `String` can be parsed as a `Double`?

Comment: You've really got me curious.. yes it results in `Infinity` which seems like a clear bug. Android uses OpenJDK 6? BTW it wouldn't be parsing it as e<sup>1234</sup> if this theory is right but 10<sup>1234</sup> but same idea.

Comment: Right, because of scientific notation. For example, 1.5e2 = 150. In my case I guess it's parsing 1e1234, and since the maximum exponent for a double is 1023, it estimates it as `Infinity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fastest way to check if a String can be parsed to Double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564896/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-can-be-parsed-to-double-in-java)

The answer on this post works on android. I have tested it on ICS.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to validate yourself if you don't trust the framework.  Here's an example of one way to do this.

```
    // You can get much fancier than this to handle all cases, but this should handle most
    String regexDouble = "^-?\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$";
    boolean isDouble = val.matches(regexDouble);
```